# Worklight Cordova Application SplashScreen Rotates During Application Launch

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, splash-screen, portrait

My application supports Portrait Mode in some pages and Landscape Mode in others, so in the case of the IOS version of the application I have Portrait, Landscape Left and Landscape Right turned on but restricted in the View Controllers. I have noticed however that during startup of the application when the Splash Screen is displayed it allows rotation. Wondering if the only way around this is to include additional assets for the Landscape version of the Splash Screen image.

Using Worklight 6.2 and Cordova 3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I did not notice the application rotating while the splash screen is displayed, ... but anyway, you can solve this in 2 ways:

1. As your wrote -  provide "proper" splash images, but I think that would still be odd looking. Or
2. Create a custom splash screen behavior; basically implement the Objective-C code that will disallow the rotation during the initialization stage of the application.

   For this, you can read the following documents:

   - [Common UI controls](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/05_02_Common_UI_Controls.pdf) training module, starting slide #29
   - [Managing the splash screen](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_splash_screen_ios.html) user documentation topic